# Como executar um callback após um "ng-show" ou "ng-hide"?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-animate

Estou usando o angular juntamente com o [ngAnimate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate). Com o [ngAnimate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate) é possível adicionar algumas classes css no elemento em que se aplica `ng-hide`ou `ng-show` para aplicar uma animação de transição.

Preciso executar um `callback` ao término de uma animação `ng-show` ou `ng-hide`. Essas animações são feitas através de classes que defini no `css`.

Exemplo:

```
<div ng-show="loading" class="animate">Carregando</div>

<div ng-hide="loading" class="animate">Isso aqui só pode mostrar quando a div acima for oculta</div>
```

Ou seja, quando a variável `loading` for `false`, preciso a div `#loading` seja removida e a `#content` seja exibida, porém somente depois que `#loading` estiver oculta.

O problema que estou tendo é que as duas estão em atividade ao mesmo tempo. Quer dizer, enquanto uma está ocultando, a outra já aparece. Isso faz com que a tela dê um pulo lá embaixo e depois fique normal.

Existe alguma maneira de executar um `callback` após o término de uma animação feita com `ng-show` ou `ng-hide`?

Exemplo no [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ny8eLxr8/94/)

Comment: Da pra colocar um demo https://plnkr.co/ ?

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues atualizado

Comment: Entendi, por que você não diminui o tempo da `  transition: all 1.2s linear;` para `0.6` já da uma diferença;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você pretende apenas criar o efeito visual e exibir o conteúdo somente após a tela de carregamento ter sumido e ainda assim poder usar o mesmo `$scope` para controlar quando cada `div` será exibida/escondida, pode obter o resultado apenas com outra classe de animação com um *delay*. Exemplo:

```
//CSS
.animate{
    transition: all 1s linear;
}
.animate-in {
    transition: all 1s linear;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 1s; //Delay
    transition-delay: 1s; //Delay
}
.animate.ng-hide,
.animate-in.ng-hide{
    opacity:0;
    color:red;
}

//HTML
<div ng-hide="loading" class="animate-in">Isso aqui só pode mostrar quando a div acima for oculta</div>
```

Deste modo basta atribuir a classe `animate-in` para o elemento que deve aparecer após a `div` "carregando" sumir e controlar o tempo de *delay* com base no tempo de animação da `div` de "carregando". Veja um exemplo funcionando: http://jsfiddle.net/qak4jk26/

Você pode fazer esse controle dentro do próprio `AngularJS` também usando outro `$scope`, exemplo `$scope.loadingIn`, mas seria pior do que usar apenas `CSS`, pois estaria usa mais um `watcher`

Comment: Transition-delay "atrasa" então o processo de "exibição"?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Essa é a ideia. Ele vai apenas fazer com que a animação inicie após `x` segundos. `transition` define o tempo que a animação vai demorar para finalizar. `transition-delay` define quanto tempo esperar para que a animação se inicie.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters veja este exemplo com os tempos mais "exagerados" http://jsfiddle.net/qak4jk26/1/ ele possui apenas 0.3s de duração da animação, mas com um delay de 5s.